# I cleared the the cache of my android studio's project and now my project is not running

Tags: android, android-studio

I cleared the cache of my `Android Studio` and then I run the same project again and It is showing a pop up window. But Every other project is working fine.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried sync with gradle file?

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked.

Answer (score -1):

Syncing the project with gradle file was the solution. Thank You Sunny.